# Dynamo DB provisionedthroughput for paginated query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a small doubt regarding the READ capacity unit consumption when i **query** a dynamo db table with a **LIMIT** set on it.
Say my query expression **could** return 100 matching items if i iterate it with `LastEvaluatedKey` but if the limit is set to 20 and i dont iterate all pages( i want top 20 only) then how much read capacity unit will be consumed ?
 Is it going to be for 100 items or only for the retrieved 20 items?
I have read the documentation but could not find anything clearly mentioning the paginated cases.

Answer (score 3):

Here, throughput is the data sent over the network.
When you specify some limit (20 in your case) then only that number of rows are transfered at that time. And in case of no limit, maximum of 1 MB of data will be send.

Number of read capacity unit consumed on some query depends upon the size of your result.
In case of read operations - 4KB = 1 unit 
and for write operations - 2KB = 1 unit.

For example if you query returned 15KB of data then your read units consumed will be - 15/4 = 4 read units.

Answer (score 1):

The Limit parameter will tell DynamoDB how many items to examine.  The Read Capacity Units consumed by that query will depend on the size of the items in your table.  You will consume the RCU necessary for DynamoDB to look at the first 20 items.

If you are using a filter, you may not receive all 20 of those items.  If you have a filter and you need 20 results, you will need to count the number of results and paginate until you have received 20 results.  DynamoDB cannot do that counting for you.

Reference: [DynamoDB Documentation for Limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#ScanQueryLimit)